# Old raleigh folder

Tags: folding-bicycle

[image]Somebody gave me a raleigh folder.Despite being left outside for several years it runs smooth and tyres stay up!!I was just wondering about the folding hinge-see pics.Is it just the thumb nut that is threaded?[image]

Comment: Could you please add another photo of the hinge/clamp on the bike frame?

Comment: Looks about right to me. I assume it is working as intended? The angled lever should be excentric where it goes through the hole in the screw, thus applying the required force when it's twisted into place.

Comment: thanks for your reply-not quite sure what you mean by eccentric.The angled lever does seem to tighten slightly but thumb nut locks it in place.Anyhow the thing seems solid up to now after a few rides.Btw its not rust its patina